# AAR Android Library - disable compression on assets

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aar

I have to distribute some files under `assets` in my AAR that should not be compressed.

So for example, in an Android app you would do the following in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'dll'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to apply this from an AAR file? I would rather not have to include instructions for developers consuming my AAR to modify their `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to set gradle build settings from inside an AAR.

However, I am making a gradle plugin anyway, so I plan to ship a gradle plugin along with the AAR.

So in my plugin I'm doing this:

```
class AaptOptionsTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    def run() {
        project.configure(project) {
            project.android.aaptOptions.setProperty('noCompress', 'dll')
        }
    }

    AaptOptionsTask() {
        group = 'myGroup'
        description = 'aaptOptions settings'
    }
}
```

Which is setup as a task like this:

```
class MyGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('aaptOptionsTask', type: AaptOptionsTask)
        project.tasks.getByName('preBuild').dependsOn('aaptOptionsTask')
    }
}
```

If there is another way, I'm all ears.

Comment: Hello @jonathan, thanks for sharing this solution about adding an aaptOptions from an AAR config to Application project. In other hand, i'm wondering if this solution can work in generated AAR means when we use the aar as external builded dependency ?